# How to get rows with distinct/unique id and no record in the left join

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to return a list of records with the id and name of a contact.
Where there is only 1 of each contact and the contact is not assigned to the task I'm trying to get the list for.

I've 2 tables, for the question I've removed all non related columns.

table 1 : contacts

```
+---------------------+-----------+
|   id (primary, AI)  |   name    | 
+---------------------+-----------+
|   1                 |   John    |
|   2                 |   Mary    |
|   3                 |   Jeff    |
|   4                 |   Bill    |
|   5                 |   Bob     |
+---------------------+-----------+
```

table 2 : tasks

```
+------------+-----------------+
|   task_id  |   contact_id    | 
+------------+-----------------+
|     2      |        1        |
|     2      |        2        |
|     1      |        1        |
|     3      |        1        |
|     4      |        1        |
+------------+-----------------+
```

I've tried several things, but I'm not getting what I'm looking for.

In the below examples, I'm trying to get the list for task_id 2.

This query following comes close, as 'Mary' is already assigned and now not showing in the results, but 'John' is still in there, as he is assigned to other tasks.
For the example I've added the task column in the results, this is not needed.

```
SELECT c.name as name, c.id as contact_id, t.task_id as task 
FROM contacts as c 
LEFT JOIN tasks as t ON t.contact_id = c.id AND t.task_id != 2
```

Returns:

```
+-------+-----------+--------+
|   id  |   name    |  task  |
+-------+-----------+--------+
|   1   |   John    |   1    |
|   3   |   Jeff    |  null  |
|   4   |   Bill    |  null  |
|   5   |   Bob     |  null  |
|   1   |   John    |   3    |
|   1   |   John    |   4    |
+-------+-----------+--------+
```

And if I move the `AND t.task_id != 2` part to the `WHERE`, I only get `'John'`:

```
SELECT c.name as name, c.id as contact_id, t.task_id as task 
FROM contacts as c 
LEFT JOIN tasks as t ON t.contact_id = c.id 
WHERE t.task_id != 2
```

Returns:

```
+-------+-----------+--------+
|   id  |   name    |  task  |
+-------+-----------+--------+
|   1   |   John    |   1    |
|   1   |   John    |   3    |
|   1   |   John    |   4    |
+-------+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is all the rows from the table `contacts` for which there is no row in the table `tasks` with `task_id = 2` you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select * from contacts c
where not exists (
  select 1 from tasks t
  where t.contact_id = c.id and t.task_id = 2
)
```

Or with `NOT IN`:

```
select * from contacts
where id not in (select contact_id from tasks where task_id = 2)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=984d746c315092ec70ada8596761514b).
Results:

```
> id | name
> -: | :---
>  3 | Jeff
>  4 | Bill
>  5 | Bob
```

Comment: I was overthinking this way to hard...So simple. Is there any performance difference between the 2, if you scale this up?

Comment: No I don't believe there is any significant difference. Sometimes not exists is very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is first to find all the contacts who are assigned to the tasks, and then remove them from the table by subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT contact_id FROM tasks GROUP BY contact_id)
```